# how to convert a string into operator in c#

Tags: c#, string

Im trying to convert a string called symbol into an operator (+ = - /) for a calculator. Instead of having only one symbol that is already chosen before, the user will choose what symbol to use (the result wont work since its not an operator).

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double num01;
        double num02;
        string symbol;
        Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
        num01=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Write the second number");
        num02=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a mathematic symbol");
        symbol=Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        double result = ( num01 symbol num02 );
        Console.WriteLine ("The result is " + result); 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a switch statement or if/else statements?

Answer (score 3):

You should create an additional method that will take your symbol and integers and perform the necessary calculation.

```
private int Calculate(string operator, int number1, int number2)
{
    if (operator == "+")
    {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
    else if (operator == "-")
    {
        return number1 - number2;
    }
    else if (operator == "*")
    {
        return number1 * number2;
    }
    else if (operator == "/")
    {
        return number1 / number2;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected operator string: " + operator);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yay C# overloaded operators!